# Erro ao configurar o perfil no WebSphere via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, middleware, java-ee-7, ibm

Ao tentar configurar o WebSphere no Eclipse não aparece a pasta onde os perfis criados estão localizados (img screen-1) para selecionar os perfis, ao tentar configurar via "Run Profile Managemente Tool" (img-Screen-2) recebo um tela de erro. O Eclipse já está sendo executado como administrador.

**Tela-1**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Tela-2**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Tela-3**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido estava faltando duas variaveis de Ambiente
WAS_HOME
WAS_HOME_IBM7

adicionando essas duas e direcionando até a pasta AppServer do WebSphere funcionou.